# Dynamics 365: Issues applying deploy-able package with LCS

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am having trouble deploying a custom solution via LCS.

I’ve created a deployable package in Visual Studio containing a custom solution.  I’ve successfully added and validated y deployable package in the Asset Library.
I’m following an article on learn.microsoft.com to apply the deployable package to my environment.

I want to apply the package using LCS, but can’t find the links mentioned in the article.

The step I’m stuck at is  on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/deployment/apply-deployable-package-system 
in section “Apply a package in a non-production environment using LCS”.
My LCS does not have an "Environment details" view.
Furthermore, the article mentions a Maintain > Applu updates function.  I cannot see any links or buttons mentioning either maintain or updates.

Could it be a lack of sufficient rights on my account?

Answer (score 1):

In your LCS project > when you click on an environment to open. You will find an option as *Full Details* rather than "Environment Details". Once you click on *Full Details* . It should show you a toolbar on top where you will find *Maintain * button. If not then check your access/permission level under Option (Clicking on Burger sign icon) and "Project Users". You should have alteast project team member role to access the LCS. Let me know if you still have an issue. If possible paste a screen shot and will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the environment you want to apply the package. 
In the top menu click **maintain** then click **apply package**.
Select the package containing your custom solution.

Then click apply.